# Как правильно составить SQL запрос по двум таблицам

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Как правильно составить SQL запрос по двум таблицам одновременно.
Например дано:
Таблицы: `table_a` и `table_b`.
В таблицах есть одинаковый столбец `name`.
Некоторые значения в таблицах повторяются. Например повторяются есть имена Вася, Майк, Александр и пр.
Пытаюсь делать запрос, чтобы найти одинаковые имена:

`SELECT * FROM table_a, table_b WHERE name LIKE '%Alexandr';`

Получается не то, а именно находится Александр только из первой таблицы.

Прошу подсказать как составить  SQL-запрос, который должен отображать одинаковые имена из двух таблиц, если имя есть в одной таблице, но нет в другой - тогда выводить значения из той таблицы, в которой есть имя

Comment: приведите пример входных данных и что должно получиться на выходе. Из текущего текста вопроса не ясно, что должно быть получено. На текущий момент я больше склоняюсь к тому что файтически вам надо отдельно искать в первой и второй таблице , а потом объединить результат (что делается с помощью `select name from table_a where .... UNION ALL select name from table_b where ...`

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за отзыв. Вопрос поправил, привел пример.

Comment: *чтобы одинаковые имена выводились сразу из двух таблиц* Именно одинаковые, и именно из двух? т.е. если есть в одной, но нет в другой - не выводить, есть есть в одной два раза и нет в другой - всё равно не выводить, так?

Comment: @Akina, спасибо что поправили, вопрос не корректен. Тогда с учетом изменений SQL-запрос должен отображать одинаковые имена из двух таблиц, если есть в одной, но нет в другой - тогда выводить значения из той таблицы, в которой есть имя

Comment: Предлагаю дополнить вопрос примером исходных данных и результата. В вариантах: нет ни в одной; есть в одной 1 запись; есть в обеих по 1 записи; есть в одной 2 записи; есть в одной 1 запись, в другой 2 записи; есть в обеих по 2 записи. Что именно надо получить в каждом из вариантов. А заодно - покажите всё же желаемую структуру выходного набора.

Comment: @Mike, оформите ответ, ваш вариант оказался более подходящим для меня. Воспользовался вашим советом и применил `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE name = 'Alexandr'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE name = 'Alexandr'
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо присвоить алиасы:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a AS a, table_b AS b WHERE a.name = b.name;
```

здесь `WHERE a.name = b.name` потому что вы написали, что хотите найти одинаковые имена.

Comment: Спасибо, только этот запрос выводит все одинаковые имена из двух таблиц. А вопрос немного в другом. Имя заранее известно.  Например: `LIKE '%Alexander';` и тогда из таблиц выведутся все Александры =)

Comment: Тогда смотрите комметарий @Mike про `UNION ALL`

Comment: *А вопрос немного в другом. Имя заранее известно.* Ну добавьте условие, будет `WHERE a.name = b.name AND a.name LIKE '%Alexander'`.

Comment: Тогда, в выборку попадут только Александры, которые есть сразу в обоих таблицах. А если в одной "1st Alexander", а в другой "2nd Alexander", то они не выведутся